# Core Plot: How to put data label always on top of a bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-plot

I have created a bar chart using Core Plot (1.1) and would like to plot all data labels above their bars.

**Problem**: There is no data label shown for the bar with the negative value.

**Question**: How can I plot the data label plotted for the negative bar on top of the bar?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this. You could suppress the labels for the negative bars and draw them yourself using plot space annotations.